# Jenkins Multiple SCM - All SCM's triggering build

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job that includes an Android app and a common library.  I use Jenkins' Multiple SCM plugin to download both git repos and then build and run.

The common library gets updated more frequently than the app, and sometimes these updates break compatibility with the App.  When the App gets updated and committed, its generally guaranteed to have fixed any incompatibilities against the latest library version.

The jenkins job should trigger *only* for commits to the App.  Under the common lib SCM, I have added "Don't trigger a build on commit notifications" as well as "Polling ignores commits from certain users" excluding "*".

However, this job still gets run when commits happen to the lib, resulting in a lot of broken build notifications.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you figure out a solution for it?

Answer (score 7):

under SCM 'Advanced clone behaviors', select 'Polling ignores commits in certain paths' and set 'Excluded Regions' to '.*'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to switch from polling to post-commit hook, like described [here](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/)?

Comment: of course ... but that's not always an option given network policies